# Firebase Hosting Deployment Error HTTP 400 Error

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I was trying to redeploy my react app on firebase after fixing some issues. But redeploying is giving errors. Not sure what the problem is.

I also tried to look into the answers provided in other posts but nothing worked for me.

**firebase.json** details below:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html",
      "headers": [{
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "max-age=0"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

> **Error: HTTP Error: 400, hosting.rewrites[0] is not exactly one from
>   [subschema 0],[subschema 1]**

This is the first time I have come across this error. So no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers options look line inside of `rewrites` parameters. instead, you need to move out as:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }],
    "headers": [{
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "max-age=0"
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okays so the problem was the headers. Removing it solved the issue. I had kept it there so that the website will reload when the user refreshes the website after it's been updated. It was working fine previously. Dont know what the issue is.  Going to keep this open if someone else can solve this issue or tell me what I did wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `source` option for the headers, take a look at how I structured mine:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/service-worker.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The documentation for how to structure the headers is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers).

Answer (score 0):

```
"hosting": {
"public": "build",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [{
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
}],
"headers": [{
    "key": "Cache-Control",
    "value": "max-age=0"
}]
```

}